# How to make a colored table in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I would like to create a colored table in greys like in here: but the code there does not run in overleaf.

This is the code of my table in overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l}
\cline{3-12}
& & \multicolumn{10}{ c| }{Primes} \\ \cline{3-12}
& & Consumer Products and Services & Wholesale & Healthcare & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 20 & 21\\ \cline{1-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }\multirow{2*Powers} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Consumer Products and Services} & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & \\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Wholesale} & \g{100.00} &  \gradient{3.00} &  \gradient{1.00} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Healthcare} & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{2-12}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{} &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &\\ \cline{1-12}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```